# How to show $A$, $B$, and $C$ are independent?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[image]

So I know $$ (A\cap B \cap C) \cup (\overline{A} \cap B\cap C) = B\cap C$$.

But we don't know if $P(B\cap C) = P(B) * P(C)$

So how do I show that it's true?

Comment: A hint to show that $P(B\cap C)= P(B)P(C)$: recall that $P(B\cap C) = P(B\cap C\cap A)+ P(B\cap C\cap\overline{A})$.

Comment: $P(B)P(C)(1+P(\overline{A})) = P(B\cap C)$

Answer (score 1):

As you say, we know $$(A\cap B \cap C) \cup (\overline{A} \cap B\cap C) = B\cap C$$

Note that the two events on the left-hand side are mutually exclusive so $$P(A\cap B \cap C) + P(\overline{A} \cap B\cap C) = P(B\cap C)$$

By hypothesis, this gives

$$P(A)P(B)P(C)+P(\overline{A})P(B)P(C)=P(B\cap C)$$

$$(P(A)+P(\overline{A}))(P(B)P(C))=P(B\cap C)$$
$$1\cdot P(B)P(C)=P(B\cap C)$$
$$P(B)P(C)=P(B\cap C)$$

Comment: The thing is, I said $P(B\cap C) = P(B)P(C)$ but my Prof. said we don't know if that's true, so I don;t know how to show that.

Comment: Yes, but if you follow my suggestion, you will *prove* that $P(B\cap C) = P(B)P(C)$  Do you have a question about what I said?

Comment: $$P(A \cap B \cap C) + P(\overline{A} \cap B \cap C) = P (B \cap C)$$
$$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(B \cap C) - P(\overline{A} \cap B \cap C)$$

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are mutually exclusive, then P(X\cupY)=P(X)+P(Y)$

Comment: Right I understand that, but we don't know if B and C are mutually exclusive so we can't say $P(B \cap C) = P(B)P(C)$

Comment: I dont get how you go from $P(B \cap C)$ to $P(B \cup C)$

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: $P(B)P(C)(1+P(\overline{A})) = P(B\cap C)$

Comment: I really don't know where to go from this.

Comment: This is a complete proof.  If you have questions, be specific.  What line don't you understand?

Comment: Nevermind. I messed up my factoring. I get it now.